# How to make auto-increment number start with (001…009, 011…099)?

Tags: java, android, auto-increment

Please help me, I don't know how to create an auto-incrementing number that starts with 001 - 999 in Android studio..

I want to play audio from url like [this](http://www.everyayah.com/data/Alafasy_64kbps/001001.Mp3).

I want to modify 001001 to 001002, 001003 >> 001099 etc

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you can use this snippet to generate your desired sequence:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        String res = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "001%03d", i);
    }
```

Comment: Or, of course, go between 1001 and 1100, and format with `%06d`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert number 1 to String "001" via below code:

```
  int num = 1; 
  String var = String.format("%03d", num); // var is "001"
  int num = 99; 
  String var = String.format("%03d", num); // var is "099"
```

and you could split 001001-001099 into two strings, each string has three digits.

Comment: it seems your snippet only generates 2 Strings!